# Displaying DataRow results in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having difficulty getting my DataRow results to display in a table on a partial view. Basically what I am trying to do is pass the results of a SQL query to a partial view and display the results in a table. Note the results will vary every time so I cannot hard code any of the column names, they must be dynamically created by my code.

This is my controller action, its purpose is to run a sql query and pass the results to the partial view in question. Please note the connection string has been removed from the code as it contains username and password but it is present and working on my code, also note that I have debugged this and the list I am returning has the data I expected it to have.

```
List<DataRow> list = null;

string connString = "Connection String Goes Here";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(custSQL, conn))
    {
        objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
        conn.Open();
        adp.Fill(dt);

        if (dt != null)
        {
            list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
    }
}

return PartialView("_CustomSQL", list);
```

This is the view, Note I am getting red line errors under DataRow and DataColumn I only wrote this code to better illustrate what I am trying to achieve which is to display the results of my SQL query in a html style table:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                {
                    <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be better to use a ViewModel for your view instead of a list of DataRows. I would create a ViewModel that reflects what your view is supposed to render. In your controller, get the values from your db, populate your ViewModel and pass it to your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a "List" as the model, so your view should be a foreach for each DataRow:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model)
            {
                foreach(System.Data.DataColumn col in row.Columns)
                {
                  <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model)
        {
          <tr>
           @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
           {
               <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
           }
          </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am getting red line errors under the DataColumn and Model.Columns, I put them in just to better illustrate what I am trying to do

Comment: It still is giving errors under the DataRow and DataColumn, am I missing a using statement?

Comment: Two things `DataRow` doesn't contain a definition for `Columns`. And in your second `foreach`, `col` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `DataTable`:

```
return PartialView("_CustomSQL", dt); // dt would be  out of scope in your code and you'll manage that
```

And in your view:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data

<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
           {
               <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
           }
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
       {
           <tr>
               @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
               {
                   <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
               }
           </tr>
       }
   </tbody>
```

Comment: Using your code I was able to get the table headings displaying but I cannot get the table data to display, you have "<td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>" should this be something like ColumnData?

Comment: @CathalO'Donnell Yes, it retrieved the value of the column at the current row. May be apply `ToString()`. `<td>@row[col.ColumnName].ToString()</td>`

Comment: @CathalO'Donnell As a side note, you really need to consider using viewmodels.